# Sending csv-file with curl Php

Tags: php, curl, rest

I try to make a PUT request with curl. I need to send a csv file with stock update. When I execute my script I get the response code 200 but the file is not sending. The csv file is in the same directory.

```
<?php
try {
  
    $file_name= "file_test.csv"; 
    
    
    $api_key= "my-key";
    $Client_id= "my-id";  
 
    $ch = curl_init("https://merchants-connector-importer.zalandoapis.com/".$Client_id."/".$file_name);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $data = array('file' =>curl_file_create($file_name, 'text/csv'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 
            "x-api-key: ".$api_key,
            "Content-Type: application/csv",
            "cache-control: no-cache"));
                       

    $content = curl_exec($ch);

    if ($content === false) {
        echo "ERROR";
        throw new Exception(curl_error($ch), curl_errno($ch));
    }else{
      var_dump($content);
      $decodedJson = json_decode($content, true);
      var_dump(http_response_code());
    }


} catch (Exception $e) {
    trigger_error(
        sprintf(
            'Curl failed with error #%d: %s',
            $e->getCode(),
            $e->getMessage()
        ),
        E_USER_ERROR
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) you do not need **CurlFile** in the **CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS** for that, because it is no **POST** request. I've also noticed the content-type for **CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER** should be the mime type `text/csv` instead of `application/csv` and **CURLOPT_UPLOAD** is set to true.

> The file to PUT must be set with **CURLOPT_INFILE** and **CURLOPT_INFILESIZE**.

Not tested, but I hope you get the right hint out of it.

```
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $file_name);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($file_name));

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
        "x-api-key: " . $api_key,
        "Content-Type: text/csv"
    ]);

    $content = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: why do we need api key, I don't have any api_key. Please tell me how to use this without api key

Comment: @GireeshDoddipalli The OP used that and I corrected his code. If you need a key, ask the API vendor. Most have a (dev) login where to obtain it.

Answer (score 0):

When I execute my code local it works fine. But when I try  to execute it from my server it does not work anymore.

```
 <?php
    try {
  
    $file_name= "test-file.csv"; 
    $api_key= "my-key";
    $Client_id= "my-id";  
    $file =fopen(__DIR__."/".$file_name, "r");
    $ch = curl_init("https://merchants-connector-importer.zalandoapis.com/".$Client_id."/".$file_name);
    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE,  $file);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($file_name));
    
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 
            "x-api-key: ".$api_key,
            "Content-Type: text/csv",
            "cache-control: no-cache"));
                       

    $content = curl_exec($ch);

    if ($content === false) {
        echo "ERROR";
        throw new Exception(curl_error($ch), curl_errno($ch));
    }else{
      var_dump($content);
      $decodedJson = json_decode($content, true);
      var_dump(http_response_code());
    }


    } catch (Exception $e) {
    trigger_error(
        sprintf(
            'Curl failed with error #%d: %s',
            $e->getCode(),
            $e->getMessage()
        ),
        E_USER_ERROR
    );
    }
```